# SharedPreferences with NumberPicker

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, numberpicker

Okay so put simply i am trying to save and then load data to and from a NumberPicker. The NumberPicker values are set initially with a string array as specific values are required to be chosen from in the NumberPicker setDisplayedValues() method is used.

I dont have any trouble saving its just when it comes to loading. because im guessing i need to give the index of the position in which that value is found in the array. This is what i have been trying but to no avail

```
minSpinNP.setValue(Integer.parseInt(spinValues[minSpinPos]));
maxSpinNP.setValue(Integer.parseInt(spinValues[maxSpinPos]));
```

Ibelieve numberPicker must take an int or an array of strings.
I am also getting this error when loading the prefs()

```
12-12 19:57:34.724: E/AndroidRuntime(7612): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
12-12 19:57:34.724: E/AndroidRuntime(7612):
at   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
12-12 19:57:34.724: E/AndroidRuntime(7612):     
at sweetbix.android.shredbox.JumpSettings.loadPrefs(JumpSettings.java:228)
```

any help would be appreciated :)

global variables

```
SeekBar switchSlider;
RadioGroup directionRadioGroup;
RadioButton fsRadioBtn;
RadioButton bsRadioBtn;
RadioButton fsBsRadioBtn;
RadioButton dirOffRadioBtn;
SeekBar corkSlider;
SeekBar spinSlider;
SeekBar grabSlider;
NumberPicker minSpinNP;
NumberPicker maxSpinNP;
Button saveBtn;

boolean safe;
int maxSpinPos;
int minSpinPos;


private int switchProbability;
private int corkProbability;
private int spinProbability;
private int grabProbability;
private int spin = 0;
private int minSpin;
private int maxSpin;
private String[] spinValues = new String[8];
```

strings added to spinValues

```
for (int i = 0; i < spinValues.length; i++) {
        String rotation = Integer.toString(spin += 180);
        spinValues[i] = rotation;
    }
```

the save method used,

```
private void savePrefs(String key, int value){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

onchangelistener for the numberpicker, somecode commented but shows what i have tried.

```
maxSpinNP.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal,
                int newVal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //maxSpin = Integer.parseInt(spinValues[maxSpinNP.getValue()]);
            //maxSpin = spinValues[maxSpinNP.getValue()];
            maxSpinPos = Arrays.asList(spinValues).indexOf(maxSpin);
            Toast.makeText(JumpSettings.this,"maxspinpos:"+ maxSpinPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    });
```

calling the save method

```
savePrefs("MIN_SPIN_JUMPS", minSpinPos);
savePrefs("MAX_SPIN_JUMPS", maxSpinPos);
```

finally calling the loadprefs method, more code commented

```
private void loadPrefs(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    switchProbability = prefs.getInt("SWITCH_JUMPS", 35);
    switchSlider.setProgress(switchProbability);
    corkProbability = prefs.getInt("CORK_JUMPS", 20);
    corkSlider.setProgress(corkProbability);
    spinProbability = prefs.getInt("SPIN_JUMPS", 80);
    spinSlider.setProgress(spinProbability);
    grabProbability = prefs.getInt("GRAB_JUMPS", 80);
    grabSlider.setProgress(grabProbability);
    minSpinPos = prefs.getInt("MIN_SPIN_JUMPS", 0);
    maxSpinPos = prefs.getInt("MAX_SPIN_JUMPS", 7);
    //minSpin = prefs.getString("MIN_SPIN_JUMPS", "180");
    //minSpinNP.setValue(Integer.parseInt(spinValues[minSpinPos]));
    //maxSpin = prefs.getString("MAX_SPIN_JUMPS", 1080);
    //maxSpinNP.setValue(Integer.parseInt(spinValues[maxSpinPos]));
    Log.e("min", "" + minSpinPos);
    Log.e("max", "" + maxSpinPos);
    //Log.e("prob", switchProbability + "");
}
```

this is line 228

```
minSpinPos = prefs.getInt("MIN_SPIN_JUMPS", 0);
```

Comment: You're using String instead of Integer somewhere, hence the exception. Show your code for loadPrefs() and indicate which line is 228.

Comment: At which line it is generate?

Comment: maxSpinNP is a integer??

Comment: Please add the code to your original post, it will be clearer. Also, add code where you're declaring spinValues and which line is 228.

Comment: maxSpinNP is the name for that numberPicker

Comment: MIN_SPIN_JUMPS is not saved as a string it is saved as an int as it uses the savePrefs(String key, int value) method

Comment: have you declared minSpinPos globally?

Comment: sorry if i do not respond to any comments til later on, its 1am where i am and need to get some sleep but will check back ASAP :)

Comment: yes, all variables have been declared globally

Comment: spinValues is an array of strings

Comment: minSpin and maxSpin is to hold a value from the spinValues array and minSpinPos and maxSpinPos is to hold the index of that values position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. i used this in the load preferences method

```
for( int i=0; i<spinValues.length ; i++ )
        if( spinValues[i].equals(maxSpinPos) )
             maxSpinNP.setValue(i);
```

numberpicker takes an int value and i thought i was getting an int value when i was trying to get the array index but i was actually getting the index and setting the variable to the value of that index

yay :)